# Implementing xunit in a new programming language

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, xunit

Some of us still "live" in a programming environment where unit testing has not yet been embraced. To get started, the obvious first step would be to try to implement a decent framework for unit testing, and I guess xUnit is the "standard".

So what is a good starting point for implementing xUnit in a new programming language?

BTW, since people are asking: My target environment is Visual Dataflex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Pragmatic Unit Testing in C# with NUnit](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/utc2/pragmatic-unit-testing-in-c-with-nunit) very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Which language is it for - there are quite a few in [place already](http://opensourcetesting.org/unit_misc.php).

Comment: For me specifically, I am looking into implementing unit testing on Visual Dataflex. My question is intended to be lanugage-agnostic, though.

Answer (score 2):

If this is stopping you from getting started with writing unit tests you could start out without a testing framework.

Example in C-style language:

```
void Main() 
{
  var algorithmToTest = MyUniversalQuestionSolver();
  var question = Answer to { Life, Universe && Everything };

  var actual = algorithmToTest(question);
  var expected = 42;
  if (actual != expected) Error();

  // ... add a bunch of tests
}
```

Example in Cobol-style language:

```
MAIN.
  COMPUTE EXPECTED_ANSWER = 42
  SOLVE ANSWER_TO_EVERYTHING GIVING ACTUAL_ANSWER
  SUBTRACT ACTUAL_ANSWER FROM EXPECTED_ANSWER GIVING DIFFERENCE
  IF DIFFERENCE NOT.EQ 0 THEN
    DISPLAY "ERROR!"
  END-IF

  * ... add a bunch of tests
  STOP RUN
```

Run Main after you are finished with a changed (and possibly compile) on your code. Run main on the server whenever someone submits code to your repository.

When you get hooked, Look more for a framework or see if you possibly could factor out some of the bits from Main to your own framework.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that a good starting point would be to use xunit on a couple of other languages to get a feel for how this style of unit test framework works. Then you'll need to go in depth into the behaviour and start working out how to recreate that behaviour in a way that fits with your new language.

Answer (score 1):

I created a decent unit test framework in VFP by basing it on the code in [Test Driven Development: A Practical Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131016490), by David Astels.  You'll get a long way by reading through the examples, understanding the techniques and translating the Java code into your language.